# HP Envy DV6 Quiet and only sees 15.6G of ram

Tags: sound, hp

First time installed Ubuntu today, I am very happy with it so far.
As the title suggests it only sees 15.6G of ram instead of 16.. I can't see this as a big issue.... but is it normal? Can I change it?
And the volumne..... I have Beats Audio and it is loud with, I hate to even say the word 'Windows', I have downloaded alsamixer and turned it up as well as clicked on sound icon, settings, allow louder than 100%. 
But it is still quiet : (
I have ubuntu 16.04 and there is an update available but it will chew up alot of my mobile data, will it help? Is there something else I can do?

Comment: Yea, the fact that you only see 15.6GB of ram is normal - some is taken by the system, BIOS / firmware or for the graphics (If you have an integrated graphics card, it may use the main system memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIRC the beats audio stuff is some extra amps that need to be turned on by hitting particular memory locations. you might have some luck with hda-jack-retask which will let you explore the possible options from a gui.

http://voices.canonical.com/david.henningsson/2011/11/29/turn-your-mic-jack-into-a-headphone-jack/

Comment: Hiya Amias, thanks for the swift reply.  I saw somewhere that the hdajackretask was now part of the mixer so I didn't do anything with it.... but I just watched https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K5uHz4zfVEU and OMG it now works better than before, so I came here to post my fix and saw your post : )

Comment: My volume is rediculously loud now, couldn't be happier, some movies still played quiet with windows, but now I have to constantly check the volume before I start something or I might blow my earballs out ha ha